# Submit a form and display text box value in another tab in AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with a `textarea` and a `button`. To show the `textarea` value in another tab of the same window on a button click I used this:

```
<input type="button" name="preview" id="inline_submit_a" value="PREVIEW" />
<script>
    $('#inline_submit_a').click(function(evt) {
        var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
        var myLineBreak = msg.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/someajax.php',
            data: "msg="+myLineBreak,
            success: function(data) {
                window.open("<?=SITEURL?>includes/templates/preview/template1/postoffer_preview.php?offer="+data,'_blank');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm sending through query string,

1. How to send the value to another page through POST and not the query string(GET) since it takes only upto limited characters.
2. Also, How to get the html content (With breaks),
   I used this: `var myLineBreak = msg.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');`
   But breaks for some text.
3. Also, `window.open("<?=SITEURL?>test.php?msg="+data,'_blank');` this works good in firefox, but in Chrome, it opens a new window,

Can someone pls help me on this.. am I going in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: instead of opening a new window why not use something like a lightbox?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using form.target and empty window.open (code not tested) :

```
<form name="myform" action="postoffer_preview.php" target="myNewWin" method=post"> 
   <input type="button" name="preview" id="inline_submit_a" value="PREVIEW" />
</form> 

<script>
    var open_post_window = function () 
    { 
        window.open("","myNewWin","width=500,height=300,toolbar=0"); 
        document.myform.submit(); 
    } 

    $('#inline_submit_a').click(function(evt) {
        var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
        var myLineBreak = msg.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/someajax.php',
            data: "msg="+myLineBreak,
            success: function(data) {
                open_post_window();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add a little setTimeout on document.myform.submit() may be necessary.